# junit тест с методом включающим Scanner (System.in)

Tags: java, junit, scanner

Пожалуйста подскажите или намекните как можно протестировать такой метод? Пользователь должен вводить ответ в консоль, но в junit там же нельзя писать, оно должно брать откуда-то значение. Как мне его туда "отправить"? Стопорюсь на этом моменте

Отдельно методы isTrue и isFalse работают и тестируются.

```
public boolean run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < REPEAT_COUNT + 1; i++) {
            System.out.println(message);
            String answer = SCANNER.nextLine();

            if (isTrue(answer)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (isFalse(answer)) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("Cant read your answer, try again");
        }

        throw new UncheckedIOException(
                new IOException("Cant read your answer more then 3 times, program close"));
    }
```

Comment: пробовали замокать это `SCANNER`?

Comment: Мок еще не проходили, этим пользоваться сейчас нельзя

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно подменить поток ввода для `Scanner`, вместо `System.in` указать другой `InputStream`.

Это можно сделать через `System.setIn(...)`

```
@Test
void runTrueAnswerTest() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("yes".getBytes());
    InputStream inputStream = System.in;  // сохраняем ссылку на ввод с клавиатуры
    System.setIn(in);                     // подменяем ввод
    CliSimpleAskView cliSimpleAskView = new CliSimpleAskView("yes or no?");
    assertTrue(cliSimpleAskView.run());
    System.setIn(inputStream);            // подменяем обратно
}

@Test
void runFalseAnswerTest() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("no".getBytes());
    InputStream inputStream = System.in;  
    System.setIn(in);
    CliSimpleAskView cliSimpleAskView = new CliSimpleAskView("yes or no?");
    assertFalse(cliSimpleAskView.run());
    System.setIn(inputStream);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! находил что-то подобное, но не понял, эту подмену нужно на время тестов сделать в основном методе, или в тест классе как-то переделать этот метод? Предыдущие более мелкие методы я тестировал прямым вызовом в тестовый метод (без изменений оригинала).

Comment: Думаю менять оригинал будет не правильно, мы же тестируем код, а не меняем. После тестов состояние кодовой базы не должно измениться. Попробуйте в тест классе делать подмену до каждого теста, а после каждого теста делать обратную подмену, там есть соответствующие аннотации (до и после каждого теста).

Comment: Сергей, пожалуйста, подскажите почему два метода не работают вместе? Как-то не верно закрываю потоки? Ниже расписал в комментарии

Comment: @Xa3uK это лучше отдельным вопросом оформить (или редактировать текущий), то что вы сделали - это написали ответ, а ответ подразумевает, что вы разобрались. Сделайте отдельным вопросом, чтобы остальные участники сервиса могли его увидеть и вам помочь. И ещё хотел сказать, если вы получили ответ и считаете его верным решением, то можете отметить это зелёной галочкой. Подробнее про галочку https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4430/Почему-не-ставят-галочку-за-правильный-ответ/4442#4442

Comment: @Xa3uK я сейчас вот в этом своём ответе напишу, как бы я сделал. В общем дополню свой ответ. Может быть это вам поможет.

Comment: Большое спасибо! С галочкой тоже разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал тестовые методы, по отдельности они работают, Scanner подменяется

```
@Test
    void runTrueAnswerTest() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("yes".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
       CliSimpleAskView cliSimpleAskView = new CliSimpleAskView("yes or no?");
        assertTrue(cliSimpleAskView.run());
        System.setIn(System.in);
        System.in.close();
        in.close();

    }

    @Test
    void runFalseAnswerTest() throws IOException {
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("no".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        CliSimpleAskView cliSimpleAskView = new CliSimpleAskView("yes or no?");
        assertFalse(cliSimpleAskView.run());
        System.setIn(System.in);
        System.in.close();
        in.close();
    }
```

Но если запустить все вместе - второй тест не отрабатывает, выдает ошибку:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
```